# Using socket.io in Asynctask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, socket.io

I make a simple game with socket.io. It well execute but, when change UI view like textview it call Thread error. So, I decide to use AsyncTask when socket.on function.
But before socket event come, onPostExecute is already done. How I can do this?

This is my code

```
 private class JoinAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {
    Boolean isDone = false;
    JSONObject object;
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        socket.on("join", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                object = (JSONObject)args[0];
                isDone = true;
                onPostExecute(true);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean done) {
        if (done) {
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
            turnChanged();
            try {
                playertwoinfo.setText(object.get("nickname").toString() + "\n" + object.get("win").toString() + "승 " + object.get("lose").toString() + "패");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think for cases like this, you should use background services.
AsyncTask is suited for small background tasks. For Socket events, you should prefer a background service which will continue to be running along with your App.
And you can update UI from that using Event Bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't invoke methods of AsyncTask manually, they will be
   invoked.Remove `onPostExecute(true);` and it will work.
2. doInBackground() is invoked from a background thread which can not
   edit properties of views. Views can be changed from UI/main thread.

Comment: No. so before the socket listens for the result I want, postExecute already is running, which makes it all screwed up since i need to use the result in the postExecute mothod

Comment: You should not call any method of  AsyncTask yourself, define a new method yourself. And you can't call `btnPlay.setEnabled(true);` from a worker thread.